# Regression with both between- and within-subjects factors

Tags: r, regression, lme4-nlme

Does a fixed between-subjects IV need to be coded differently than a within-subjects variable in a lmer model in R? Or is the model smart enough to figure out these distinctions without any explicit coding?

Note that my question is not about the difference between fixed and random effects, but rather about how to indicate different types of fixed factors in a linear-mixed model. I have read many similar forum posts on the topic, but could not get a clear, straightforward answer, so I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Not sure if this is what you are getting at, but here is an example where i have "group" as the fixed effect and the individual subject as the random effect. `library(lme4)

fit_lmer <- lmer(extra ~ group + (1|ID), data = sleep)
summary(fit_lmer)`

Comment: @user3585829 In my case, I have "experiment" as a between-subjects factor and "salience" as a within-subjects factor, in addition to random effects of subjects and items that I must analyze within the same model. So, my question is more like: Can I just enter these fixed effects into the linear-mixed model without specifying which is between- and which is within-subjects? E.g., `lmer(dv ~ salience*experiment + (1 | subj) + (1 | item) ...`

Comment: That model looks okay. The between and within subject interpretation should come out when you write up your model results. With experiment as a fixed effect, the difference will be compared to which ever class is set as the intercept (keeping in mind the interpretation given your interaction there).